# jQuery isotope special characters category filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have multiple categories where there are images, isotope is working good filtering all categories, but there is a problem when there are categories containing special characters like "PC & Notebook". If I click on the name of the category, it is not filtered by isotope and in the Chrome Console I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .PC & Notebook

This is my working code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  var $container = $('#tabpersonalcloset');

  $container.isotope({
    filter:           '*',
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 750,
      easing:   'linear',
      queue:    false
    }
  });

  $('.file-manager ul li a').click(function () {
    $('.file-manager .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
      filter:           selector,
      animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing:   'linear',
        queue:    false
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Is there a way to filter all the categories named "PC & Notebook"?

Answer (score 0):

It's the spaces between the & character and 'PC' 'Notebook'. Your data-filter can filter 'PC', 'Notebook', '&' individually but not 'PC & Notebook'.  Trying 'PC&Notebook' will work. Need to see how you set up your data-filters in html to offer other solutions